# how to efficiently construct an affinity matrix from rows of transactions?

Tags: python, json, graph, affinity, data-munging

Given transactions between nodes in a (potentially large ~ 2+GBs) json file, with ~ million nodes and ~10 million transactions each having 10-1000 nodes such as

```
{"transactions":
 [
  {"transaction 1": ["node1","node2","node7"], "weight":0.41},
  {"transaction 2": ["node4","node2","node1","node3","node10","node7","node9"], "weight":0.67},
  {"transaction 3": ["node3","node10","node11","node2","node1"], "weight":0.33},...
  ]
}
```

what would the most elegant and efficient pythonic way to convert this into a node affinity matrix, where the affinities are the sum of weighted transactions between the nodes.

```
affinity [i,j] = weighted transaction count between nodes[i] and nodes[j] = affinity [j,i]
```

e.g.

```
affinity[node1, node7] = [0.41 (transaction1) + 0.67 (transaction2)] / 2 = affinity[node7, node1]
```

Note: the affinity matrix will be symmetrical and thus computing lower triangle alone will suffice.

Values not representative*** structure example only!

node1 | node2 | node3 | node4 | ....
 node1          1          .4          .1         .9    ...
 node2         .4           1          .6         .3    ...
 node3         .1          .6           1         .7    ...
 node4         .9          .3          .7          
 1    ...
...

Comment: hi D.S. welcome to Stackoverflow. You can use the `{}` button when posting a question to format a piece of text as a code block. Code blocks preserve whitespaces and make it easier to post this like JSON

Comment: Thanks Matti, I understand, I believe the current formatting (although hard to do) looks readable, do you disagree?

Comment: It's readable but as you point out quite a bit of work to get done. It's much easier to just use the `{}` button

Comment: Hi would you provide a definition for node affinity matrix, this would increase your chances of getting an answer

Comment: Hi user2314737, I did provide an example for the resulting affinity matrix structure where the column headers and the index are the nodes and the values within the i*j th elements represent affinities which are a weighted sum of the transactions, between node i and node j. Am I still missing something?

Comment: In this particular case, it would be symmetrical, since if both nodes i and j are in a transaction, they both i.e A[i,j] and A[j,i] will have identical weights, you make a great point, since we do not need the full matrix, lower triangle will be sufficient.

Comment: But your matrix is not symmetrical. Would you write out how you compute A[i,j] for a couple of i,j based on the sample transaction data?

Comment: Added a formula, fair warning the values in the affinities example were not representative

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would clean the data and represent each node with an integer and start with a dictionary like this

```
data=[{'transaction': [1, 2, 7], 'weight': 0.41},
      {'transaction': [4, 2, 1, 3, 10, 7, 9], 'weight': 0.67},
      {'transaction': [3, 10, 11, 2, 1], 'weight': 0.33}]
```

Not sure if this is pythonic enough but it should be self-explanatory

```
def weight(i,j,data_item):
    return data_item["weight"] if i in data_item["transaction"] and j in data_item["transaction"] else 0

def affinity(i,j):
    if j<i: # matrix is symmetric
        return affinity(j,i)
    else:
        weights = [weight(i,j,data_item) for data_item in data if weight(i,j,data_item)!=0]
        if len(weights)==0:
            return 0
        else:
            return sum(weights) / float(len(weights))

ln = 10 # number of nodes
A = [[affinity(i,j) for j in range(1,ln+1)] for i in range(1,ln+1)]
```

To view the affinity matrix

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(A))
```

> ```
>     [[ 0.47  0.47  0.5   0.67  0.    0.    0.54  0.    0.67  0.5 ]
>      [ 0.47  0.47  0.5   0.67  0.    0.    0.54  0.    0.67  0.5 ]
>      [ 0.5   0.5   0.5   0.67  0.    0.    0.67  0.    0.67  0.5 ]
>      [ 0.67  0.67  0.67  0.67  0.    0.    0.67  0.    0.67  0.67]
>      [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
>      [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
>      [ 0.54  0.54  0.67  0.67  0.    0.    0.54  0.    0.67  0.67]
>      [ 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
>      [ 0.67  0.67  0.67  0.67  0.    0.    0.67  0.    0.67  0.67]
>      [ 0.5   0.5   0.5   0.67  0.    0.    0.67  0.    0.67  0.5 ]]
> ```

Comment: In this case would you store column headers as a separate list for optimal storage?

Comment: Also can you suggest the use of sparse matrices for this purpose? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html

Comment: what happens when you have potentially a million nodes.. how do you optimize?

Comment: if the matrix is sparse then I would look into an efficient data structure for sparse matrices, yes. You could also look into faster Python implementations like Pypy or Numba. Maybe you should post a new question with a concrete example of what you're using the matrix for..

Comment: Yes the data is sparse, as mentioned in the question  million nodes and 10 million transactions each having approximately about a 10-100 nodes. I would also appreciate if you can use the nodes as strings and treat the input data as json (as formatted) since iterating through the json separately is going to further add complexity and delays, I would prefer shaping the data while iterating through json